# How can I parse XML node with mixed value in PHP

Tags: php, xml

How can I parse this xml, and get url text and title node value seperated:

```
<root>
  <test>
    <gate>
        <url>http://google.com<title>Google</title></url>
    </gate>
  </test>
</root>
```

Is this possible with DomDocument or SimpleXML ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
echo $data->root->test->gate->url
```